# Particular solution to system of differential equations (with eigen- vectors & values)

Tags: calculus, limits

Given a system of differential equations

$y_1'=2y_1+y_2$

$y_2'=-2y_1+5y_2$

Which has the eigenvalues 3 and 4 for the total matrix of the above mentioned system. Where the vectors $(1,1)$ and $(1,2)$ are eigenvectors to the above mentioned eigenvalues. Such that $(1,1)$ is the eigenvector of the value 3 and the other vector of 4.

1) Find the solution for the differential system

2) Find the particular solution such that
$$\lim_{t\to \infty}   e^{-t4}y_1(t)=0$$

and $$y_2'(0)=3$$

1) I found the solution 
$c_1e^{3t}(1,1)+c_1e^{4t}(1,2)$

2) I'm uncertain with the second part. The limit creates some issues for me.

Comment: brain fart! Thank you. I've edited it now.

Comment: I do not know. It's the one that I'm having issues with. I've triple checked and it gives the contraint (or what ever term is used) as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have
$$
A =
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 \\
-2 & 5
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and
$$
y' = A y
$$
Then
$$
A (1,1)^T = (3,3)^T = 3 (1,1)^T \\
A (1,2)^T = (4,8)^T = 4 (1,2)^T
$$
The solution of the linear ODE is:
$$
0 = y' - A y = (e^{-tA}y)' \Rightarrow \\
y(t) = e^{tA} y(0)
$$
Further for an eigenvector $y_\lambda$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$ we have
$$
e^{tA} y_\lambda
=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}t^k A^k y_\lambda
=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}t^k \lambda^k y_\lambda
= e^{\lambda t} y_\lambda
$$
So here we get
$$
y(t) = c_1 e^{3t}(1,1)^T + c_2 e^{4t}(1,2)^T
$$
as general solution. This corresponds with your solution.

Applying the first condition to the general solution yields
\begin{align}
0 
&= \lim_{t\to\infty} e^{-4t} y_1(t) \\
&= \lim_{t\to\infty} e^{-4t} (c_1 e^{3t} + c_2 e^{4t}) \\
&= c_1 \left( \lim_{t\to\infty} e^{-4t} e^{3t} \right) + 
   c_2 \left(\lim_{t\to\infty} e^{-4t} e^{4t} \right)) \\
&= c_1 \left( \lim_{t\to\infty} e^{-t} \right) + 
   c_2 \left( \lim_{t\to\infty} 1 \right)\\
&= c_2
\end{align}
and further
$$
3 
= y_2'(0) 
= \left. (3 c_1 e^{3t} + 8 c_2 e^{4t}) \right\vert_{t=0}
= 3 c_1 + 8 c_2
= 3 c_1 
$$
So we get $c_1 = 1$ and $c_2 = 0$ as coefficients of the particular solution:
$$
y_p(t) =  e^{3t}(1,1)^T
$$

Comment: Thank you for the indeept answer. Why do you not substitute $y_1(t)$ with $(c_1e^{3t}(1,1)+c_2e^{4t}(1,2))$? Also I am not quite sure how you find the particular solution, specically $e^{3t}$. I understand you can test it afterwards but how you found the solution I do not understand.

Comment: regarding the particular solution; Does it derive from $c_1=0$ and therefore the entire second "part" of the general solution equals 0 and thous we have the above left?

Comment: I intepreted $y_1$ as first component of the vector $y$ and $y_2'$ as the second component.of $y'$..

Comment: Can you give me a tip or provide additional calculation on the first condition? I fail to see how you reduce it to $$c_1 \left( \lim_{t\to\infty} e^{-t} \right) + c_2$$

Comment: Thank you again, that cleared it up. I believe my understanding of how you arrive to the general solution is very poor and that may be why I did not find the particular solution. It may be much to ask, but do you have any material at hand (I've looked over Paul's online math note) or have time to write up a little more detailed explaination?

Comment: There is not much missing: Proofs for why the matrix exponential makes sense. The derivative of the matrix exponential. That a linear system of $n$ components has $n$ linear independent solutions. All what you can find in a text on ordinary differential equations.

Answer (score 0):

Write the system in matrix form, $y' = Ay$. Note that if an initial condition $y_0$ is an eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to eigenvalue $\lambda$ and we
set $y(t) = e^{\lambda t} y_0$, then
$y'(t) = \lambda e^{\lambda t} y_0 = e^{\lambda t} A y_0 = A (e^{\lambda t} y_0) = A y(t)$, so $y(t) = e^{\lambda t} y_0$ is a solution.

You are given two eigenvectors $v_1,v_2$ corresponding to eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$, so you have two solutions of the form above (in fact,
since the system is linear, any linear combination is also a solution, and since
there are two of them and the are linearly independent, the linear combinations form all of the solutions).

Now pick an eigenvector $v$ corresponding to an eigenvalue $\lambda$ so that
$e^{-4t} e^{\lambda t} v \to 0$.